# The necessity of indirect object pronouns

Tags: objetos-indirectos

For those unfamiliar with indirect object pronouns, but instead use them as native speakers, they are basically **me, te, le, nos, les**, each of which represent for me, for you, for him/her, for us, or for them.

A example of sentences using IOP :

> yo saco a pasear al perro ( i walk my dog)

This is actually from my textbook, and is the sentence in which the use of IOP conflicts with what I think is how IOP is supposed to be used.

This is what I think is correct as opposed to the previous example:

> yo saco a pasear**le** al perro

Notice it is pasearle, not pasear.

Comment: Why do you think that's correct? There is no indirect object in this example, only a direct object: *el perro*.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence is right. I was asking why do you think your example is the right one.

Comment: Because it is always yo le doy el regalo a mi amigo. It is never yo doy el regalo a mi amigo, short of the le.

Comment: So following from the same logic, it is supposed to be pasearle if there is a a.

Comment: @Doeser There is nothing wrong with "doy el regalo a mi amigo".

Comment: I don't get why my textbook would say darle de comer al gato but not sacar a pasearle al perro

Comment: Darle (de comer)DO (al gato)IO. Sacar a pasear (al perro)DO. There is no indirect object in the second

Comment: Al perro is IO not DO with a

Comment: On what basis? Are you taking something else out for a walk to help out this dog? Trying to get his doggie brother tired out?

Comment: I consider se direct object pronoun and le and les indirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19647/discussion-between-guifa-and-doeser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DPD](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd) gives good advice on this topic.  Basically, there is one exception to when you can't indirect object pronoun.  Here are the rules copied from another answer I gave a while back.

- If the object (indirect or direct) is a person pronoun (mí, ti, etc) and included anywhere in the sentence, you must include the pronoun with the verb (indirect or direct):  *Me castigaron a mí* but **not** **castigaron a mí* (*DPD* “pronombres personales átonos” 5.1)
- If the object (indirect or direct) comes before the verb (OSV or OVS sentences), you must include the pronoun with verb, animate or not: *A los problemas del mundo no les doy mucha importancia*, but **not** **A los problemas del mundo no doy mucha importancia*, except for emphatic statements (*ibid*. 5.2)
- Verbs of affection require the indirect object pronoun except for the so-called universal quantifiers (*todo*, *nadie*, etc). (*ibid*. 5.2(a))
- When you are being intentionally emphatic or contrastive, you cannot have the indirect object pronoun.  For example ***A ti*** lo daré, **a él** no.  Here, saying *Te lo daré, a él no* would sound very odd. (*ibid*. 5.2)

If the indirect object comes after the verb and isn't a personal pronoun (so *a Juan*, *a los estudiantes* or *al problema*), then it is almost always completely optional, if quite common especially in speech.  The handful of exceptions include gustar and similar verbs, which do require it except when the indirect object is a universal quantifier like *nadie*/*todo*/etc. in which case it's once again optional (*ibid*. 5.2(a)).

All this said, in your example, we're not looking at a indirect object but an direct object.  Normally, direct objects are bare/unmarked (like the subject), and indirect object pronouns are introduced with *a* or *para*.  However, some direct objects *are* introduced with *a*.  There are two situations this can happen in:

- The direct object is animate, that is, a person or an animal of roughly equal stature like pets (very common).
- The direct object could be confused for the subject (very rare).

If you wanted to use a direct object pronoun, you should use *lo*, although *le* is allowed both formally (for masculine animate singular direct object pronouns) and in leísmo non-standard usage (general use of *le* for direct object pronouns).   This is not a case, however, where the direct object allows for coappearance.  Hence, your *le* will only be interpreted as an indirect object pronoun, and we do don't know *for whom* you're taking out the dog, or, we could interpret *el perro* as for whom, but then we still don't know *who/what* you took out out for a walk.

Comment: I googled DPD with no avail. What is DPD in this context ?

Comment: @chapelo the *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas* published by the ASALE and the RAE, I've added a link and more specific citations in the answer.

Comment: I am taking the dog out for a walk. Definitely for myself, very self evident.

Comment: Le has never been to me suitable to be used for direct objects.

Comment: @Doeser then quite simply, you cannot use *le* here.

Comment: ，the explanation of my examples I wrote in the chat

Comment: «being intentionally emphatic or contrastive, you **cannot** have the indirect object pronoun» ?? the very example you gave sounds wrong to me. I would still add the `te`, i.e. "a **ti** te lo daré, a él no"

Answer (score 1):

Consider your first sentence

> Yo saco a pasear al perro (CD).
>
> Yo saco a pasearlo (el perro) or Yo lo saco a pasear

Now consider your second sentence

> Yo saco a pasear al perro (CD) a mi vecino (CI)
>
> Yo saco a pasearle (a mi vecino) el perro.
>
> Yo saco a <del>paseárlelo</del> → paseárselo. (where le is changed to se and becomes paseárselo)
>
> Yo <del>le</del> → se (CI) lo (CD) saco a pasear.

Comment: I was going to edit your question, but I don't know if "paseárlelo" is on purpose or if it is a typo.

Comment: @Diego It is definitely on purpose, just to illustrate the le and lo in the word before it is changed to se due to the spanish rules. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I thought le is to it, him, or her

Comment: Está perfecto, explica las diferencias entre las dos frases planteadas por el OP. En efecto, cuando ‘le’ y ‘lo’ se juntan, en realidad no se llevan bien. Por eso hay que cambiar a ‘se’ + ‘lo’ para evitar la cacofonía. En mi opinión esta respuesta es mucho más sintética que la otra; merece ser la respuesta aceptada.